# Jquery/json pull string with html from mysql db

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm pulling data from a `mysql` db using `php` and echoing a `json_encoded` array.

Using ajax I pull in the results and set the values of various `dom` elements. I have a string which has some html tags eg `<p></p>`.

When I set the element `$("#element").html(data['text'])` it adds double quotes to the text and all of the html elements appear as text.

I can't seem to remove the quotes using replace. Oddly when I alert the value there are no quotes. They only appear in the html when I view the code.

What is the best way to include html with text? And how do I get `jquery` to render this has html and not text?

Many thanks!

### PHP / MySQL

```
//Article by id
if(isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do']=='get_art') {
   $content = array();

   $id = clean_input($_GET['id']);
   $q = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = '$id'";
   $r = $conn->query($q);
   $row = $r->fetch_assoc();

   $content['title'] = str_replace("€", '&euro;', $row['title']);
   $content['img'] = $row['img'];

   $content['text'] = str_replace('€', '&euro;', $row['text']);
   $content['text'] = htmlentities($row['text']);

   echo json_encode($content);
}
//end article by id
```

### jQuery

```
//load article onclick
$('body').on('click', '.get_art', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', ' ');

   $.ajax({
     url: 'actions.inc.php?do=get_art&id=' + href,
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'post',
     success: function(data) {
         var art_text = data['text'];
         art_text = art_text.replace('&amp;euro;', '&euro;');

          $("#art_img").attr("src", "images/" + data['img']);
          $("#art_title").html(data['title']);
          $("#art_text").html($.parseHTML(art_text));

        } //end success
  });//end ajax

});
//end load
```

Comment: Is there any way you can share your code ?

Comment: jQuery `html` function doesn't escape quotes, so the error must be on your side. Check http://api.jquery.com/html/

It will help if you can share with us the sql result to double check what you are getting from the database and passing as param to jquery

Comment: thanks for the replies, updated above

Answer (score 0):

The htmlentities (php) was making a mess of things, got it working now after I console logged the output from the php file